# angular link requires basic auth

Tags: angularjs

I have a links within my app to documents like http://site/mydoc.pdf where the site requires basic auth to open. I've tried attaching auth in my my app like

```
      .config(function($httpProvider) {
    var auth = "user:pass";
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + auth;
    })
```

But when clicking on the link, i'm still getting the popup for credentials to continue to the document.

Comment: `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + btoa(auth);`

Comment: this didn't seem to change anything.